# How to purge (clear) all cache files in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla-2.5, cache

Documentation provides code for clearing expired cache (https://docs.joomla.org/Purging_expired_cache_files):

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Cli
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

// Make sure we're being called from the command line, not a web interface
if (array_key_exists('REQUEST_METHOD', $_SERVER)) die();

// Initialize Joomla framework
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Load system defines
if (file_exists(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/defines.php'))
{
    require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

// Get the framework.
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/import.php';

// Bootstrap the CMS libraries.
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/cms.php';

// Force library to be in JError legacy mode
JError::$legacy = true;

/**
 * Cron job to trash expired cache data
 *
 * @package  Joomla.CLI
 * @since    2.5
 */
class GarbageCron extends JApplicationCli
{
    /**
     * Entry point for the script
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     * @since   2.5
     */
    public function doExecute()
    {
        $cache = JFactory::getCache();
        $cache->gc();
    }
}

JApplicationCli::getInstance('GarbageCron')->execute();
```

It is a file garbagecron.php.

But how to clear all cache files in Joomla?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just access via ftp and clear the cache directory manually?